# Activation/deactivation of toolbar buttons using Prism

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, toolbar

I’m in the process of learning the Prism framework and I’ve come along way already. But I was wondering about how to create toolbars (and context menus) where each module can register their own buttons.

For this example I want all buttons to reside in the same ToolBar control which is located in my Shell. The ToolBars `ItemsSource` binds to a `ToolBarItems` property of type `ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>` in the view model. Elements can be added to this collection using a `ToolBarRegistry` service. This is the ViewModel:

```cs
public class ShellViewModel
{
    private IToolBarRegistry _toolBarRegistry;
    private ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> _toolBarItems;

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        _toolBarItems = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>();
        _toolBarRegistry = new ToolBarRegistry(this);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> ToolBarItems
    {
        get { return _toolBarItems; }
    }
}
```

*Note that the collection of type FrameworkElement will be refactored to be of a more concrete type if this turns out to be the correct solution.*

My `ToolBarRegistry` has a method to register image buttons:

```cs
public void RegisterImageButton(string imageSource, ICommand command)
{
    var icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageSource));

    var img = new Image();
    img.Source = icon;
    img.Width = 16;

    var btn = new Button();
    btn.Content = img;
    btn.Command = command;

    _shellViewModel.ToolBarItems.Add(btn);
}
```

I call this method from my `OrderModule` and the buttons show up correctly. So far so good.

The problem is how I can control when these buttons should be removed again. If I navigate to a view in another module (and sometimes another view in the same module), I want these module-specific buttons to be hidden again.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this? Am I approaching this problem the wrong way, or can I modify what I already have? How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not insert `Button` instances in the `ObservableCollection`. Think about this approach instead:

### Create ViewModel for the toolbar buttons

```
class ToolBarButtonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation to be provided by you

    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

Then of course change the type of `ToolBarItems` to a collection of these.

In your `ShellView`, add a `DataTemplate` for `ToolBarButtonViewModel` and bind the `ItemsSource` of whatever your toolbar control is to the collection of ViewModels, for example:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Command="{Binding Command}">
        <Button.Content>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can now bind `Button.Visibility` to `IsVisible` with a [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) to solve your immediate problem.

As an added bonus, you can also:

- Change the visual appearance of the toolbar buttons entirely from XAML
- Bind any property of the visual tree for a toolbar button to corresponding properties on the `ToolBarButtonViewModel`

### Update

The mechanism for enabling/disabling buttons depends on specifics of your application. There are many options -- here are a few (keep [this chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#TheRegionNavigationSequence) in mind while reading):

- Implement [`INavigationAware`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.inavigationaware%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) in your Views or ViewModels and enable/disable buttons as required
- Attach handlers to the [events of `IRegionNavigationService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.iregionnavigationservice_events%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) of the region(s) of interest and have the handlers enable or disable buttons
- Route all navigation through your own code (`CustomNavigationService`) and decide what to do inside it

Comment: You are right about that, and that was actually what I had in mind when I wrote that I would refactor the FrameworkElement type if this turns out to be the correct solution. However, I still cannot see how I would manage the IsVisible property. Where can I register if the user navigates away from the View/Module, and then set Visibility to Hidden for all the buttons?